# Matlab Running a parameterized fminsearch in a for loop?

Tags: matlab

Essentially I want to have fminsearch run over a variety or parameters.

So I have the following snipet of code running:

```
%Setting up the changeable WIRX parameters:
L = 0.15; %Length along the electrodes in meters
I = 3000; %Current in amps

%Running the fminsearch:
TeNe = fminsearch(@(params) TeNe(params,L,I),[5,1.5e21],optimset('MaxFunEvals', 100000,'MaxIter', 100000));
```

What I want to do is be able to run this in a for loop with an array of values for L and I. However what i noticed is that I cannot even run this piece of code twice in a row with out getting the error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `TeNe` is a function which you call with the following inputs: `(params,L,I)`.
However, the output of [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) is also assigned to `TeNe`.
That is why, after the first loop iteration you get the error you see. `L` has been set to `0.15`, however, this makes no sense as an index to an array called `TeNe` - which you end up with after running `fminsearch`.
Consider changing the name of the output variable.